# The dotted cross

Tags: visual

This is a very straightforward puzzle. Here are $25$ dots in a $5\times 5$ matrix.
$$
\begin{matrix}
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Just connect 12 dots of these dots to make a cross that has $5$ dots inside it and $8$ dots outside it?

For an editor-guy, here is a screenshot of these dots:
[image: dots]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can draw a cross that satisfies these constraints like this:

> [image]

12 dots connected, 5 dots inside, 8 outside. The trick is to realise:

> that you can draw a cross using diagonal lines rather than trying to use just horizontal and vertical connections (as a grid might automatically lead you to try).